# Python: Generate incremental sequence number programmatically each time the py file is run

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a number which is sequential in nature and depends upon previous run of a py file.

Lets take an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Desc':['This is a test sequence generator'],'Seq_Num':[100]},index=None)
```

When I run this I get the following dataframe:

```
       Desc                             Seq_Num
This is a test sequence generator         100
```

Now when I shall run the above statement again, I want `Seq_Num` as 101. So the resultant `df` would be:

```
      Desc                             Seq_Num
This is a test sequence generator         101
```

And so on. I.e. every time that .py script runs, seq_num is increased by unit 1. After, say 10 consecutive runs, the `Seq_Num` should be 110.

Any clue on this

Comment: you are telling it to use 100, it will always be 101, your code doesn't change.
 you need to store the number somewhere (a file?) and load that one and pass it as the initial number, and save it on end

Comment: Can you please show this using code snippet